# vertical-align with float and anonymous box label

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS/HTML and struggling to understand why when putting text "Title" out of div.position container label goes down. Thanks for you help.

[My code](http://jsfiddle.net/RokasL/w6kosc2v/)

CSS code:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
.position {
     float: left;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div>
    <label>Label</label>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="position">
            <input type="radio" />
        </div>
        Title
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add `label {float: left;}` - http://jsfiddle.net/avxvtqsg/

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I am more interested what are the reasons for the behaviour I've mentioned before.

Comment: that doesn't really explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for `vertical-align` is baseline.

That's why the label appears at the baseline of the parent div. (see the image)

[image]

However when the title text is within the position div the height of the div is less - that's why it looks like the label stays on top. In reality it is still at the baseline of the parent div.

If you set `vertical-align:top` on the label it will appear at the top like it should

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/w6kosc2v/3/)**

Comment: Thanks for your guide. What's more, I want to know about the compatibility of `vertical-align`.Could you afford more information? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks! And the reason the heights differ, happens due to (when use outside div.position) "title" box is not given enough space in group div and new line is added, even though the text itself appears on the first line. Fix can be done by providing group label its width.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the label float to left:

```
label {
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w6kosc2v/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article about how floating works: [All About Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) which might explain a little more about floats to you.

Shortly said a float will float to the side you set it to; `float: right` floats to the right, while an image is floated to the right, all other inline elements tend to wrap around your float, a your `<label>` tag did. You can fix this by either removing the `float: left` from your `.position` or also by adding it to the label.

I hope this awnser makes it somewhat more clear.